# Что эта запись говорит о HashMap?

Tags: android, java

1. Тут понятно, что и ключ и значение должны быть типа String, а первый и второй List о чем говорят?

   ```
   List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes
   ```
2. Я правильно понимаю, что тут создают ArrayList data, состоящий из HeshMapов (почему пишут только "Map"?), texts.length - это задают длину HashMap?

   ```
   ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(
               texts.length);
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes
```

Это список, состоящий из списков, каждый из которых состоит из `HashMap<String, String>`  
Боюсь представить, зачем такой монстр может понадобиться...

```
ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(
                texts.length);
```

тут создают ArrayList, состоящий из Map, а не HashMap. Почему так? Потому, что в результате в него можно положить что угодно, наследуемое от Map. Что именно, можно посмотреть [тут](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Answer (score 3):

В первом случае создают список списков, элементами которого будет хэшмап. Такой себе "двумерный список", что-то близкое к матрице.

Во втором случае map - это не хэшмап. Это интерфейс. И в левой части выражения быть ему нормально, а вот в правой... Это нужно проверить. Почитайте детальное о мапах, например, на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/128017/).

Comment: > И в левой части выражения быть ему нормально, а вот в правой...

Вполне нормально в данном случае. Мы можем заранее не знать, какие именно мапы будут класть в этот список. Да и это не особо важно, главное - к ним можно обращаться через интерфейс `Map`.